# Colorbox on iPad: Interactions break after zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, colorbox

There's an annoying problem with colorboxes on iPads i stumbled across: After opening a colorbox and zooming, interactive elements inside the colorbox seem to be broken.

This can be repeated on this [example webpage (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/):

1. open a colorbox on an iPad
2. zoom into the colorbox
3. try closing by clicking on the close button

I am using the iPad 2 (iOS version 6) with jQuery version v1.9.1 and colorbox version v1.3.34.

Comment: This problem does not appear after updating to iOS version 6.1.2 (10B146) anymore.